# i can't change the border style of a div using select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

I made a dropdown which is supposed to change the border style of div. I'm using select and option html tags. When the .change() event is executed, I was expecting to get the border style changed to the current select value. Please tell correct me. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Buubiye/nLp3hdnf/3/) link.

Here is the js code

```
$(function() {
   $("select").change(function() {
     var getChoice = $("select option:selected").val();
     $('.active').css('borderStyle', getChoice);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `val()` to `text()`

From:

```
$("select option:selected").val();
```

to:

```
$("select option:selected").text();
```

Comment: .val() is used for Input elements and .text() or .html() used for any other html element to get it's values.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `value` to each `option` and then use it like this:

```
<select id="me">
  <option value="volvo">Border-style</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="Solid">Solid</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="Dotted">Dotted</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="Dashed">Dashed</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="Double">Double</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="Mixed">Mixed</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="Remove">Remove</option>
</select>

$(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $('.active').css("border-style", $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/nLp3hdnf/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Id var getChoice = $("#me :selected").text();

```js
$(function(){
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var getChoice = $("#me :selected").text();
    $('.active').css('borderStyle', getChoice);
});
});
```

```css
.active{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 5px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="me">
  <option value="volvo">Border-style</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="">Solid</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="">Dotted</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="">Dashed</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="">Double</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="">Mixed</option>
  <option id="b-style" value="">Remove</option>
  
</select>

<div class="active"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your code you are repeating id. An Id should always be unique and you just have to get the value of the **select** feild.

Please refer to the below snippet

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  $('div').css({'border-style':$(this).val()});
});
```

```css
div{
width:120px;
height:120px;
border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>

</div>
  <select>
    <option value='dashed'>dashed</option>
    <option value='dotted'>dotted</option>
    <option value='double'>double</option>
    <option value='mixed'>mixed</option>
  </select>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```